# One UIView to rule them all, One UIView to bind them

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-management, uiview

I am facing an issue with two UIViews that have the same code:

The two main UIViews:

```
UIView *firstView;
UIView *secondView;
UIView *thirdView;

self->thirdView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame(100,100,100,100)];
```

Later in the code:

```
self->firstView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame(0,0,200,200)];
self->secondView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame(0,0,200,200)];
```

Then in the code I do:

```
[self->firstView addSubView:self->thirdView];
[self->secondView addSubView:self->thirdView];
```

What happens in the code is that somehow one of the views would miss out the `thirdView`, I want to know if it has anything to do with the fact that I am using the same `thirdView`.

If so, `thirdView` is important and I need to use it with both views, how can I do that?

Comment: ...one view to bring them all and in the darkness bind them.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that a view can only have one parent. If you attempt to add a view to a second parent, it will be removed from the first view, then added to the second view.

You can't add `thirdView` to both `firstView` and `secondView` at the same time. Instead, you need to create two instances of `thirdView`.